# SQL Concatenate 2 large TEXT rows from the datatype TEXT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am struggling to achieve the following:

In my cte I have 2 (or more) large text strings. I want to concatenate these into one row instead of multiple rows.

Here under is the simplified version. However with the for xml it messes up...

Any ideas or approaches?

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT CAST('<XML></XML>' as text) as Result
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('<XML AGAIN></XML AGAIN' as text) as Result
)


SELECT Result 
FROM cte p2
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably see special characters like brackets (`<` and `>`) encoded as HTML entities.

Add a `TYPE` directive to encode/decode it properly:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT CAST('<XML></XML>' as text) as Result
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('<XML AGAIN></XML AGAIN>' as text) as Result
), cte2 (XMLResult) AS
(
SELECT Result
FROM cte1
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
)

SELECT XMLResult.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM cte2
```